# ReactiveMongo with Play 2.3

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I'm working on Play 2.3 with ReactiveMongo.
I want to query the db which should search by a id and a name or a mobile number. which ever matches among the name and mobile number.

The query in the db level which worked is as follows.

```
 db.endUser.find({$and:[{businessUserId:"1"},{ $or: [{name:"Ruthvick"},{mobileNumber:"989"}]}]})
```

but the same to write as per play syntax is not fetching any result. The query in scala which didn't work is as follows.

```
val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = collectionEndUser.find(
        Json.obj("$and"->Json.arr(Json.obj("businessUserId"->"",
         "$or"->Json.arr(Json.obj("name"->"Ruthvick",
         "mobileNumber"->"9686563240")))))
              ).cursor[JsObject]
```

Kindly review the query and help me with necessary changes.

Thanks

Comment: you tried this using scala mongo salat?

Comment: I used Reactive Mongo

Comment: Some one please help me with a proper query.

Comment: is that Ok that you have `businessUserId` value as empty string in Scala and `"1"` in mongo script and `mobileNumber` value is `"9686563240"` in Scala but `"989"` in mongo script?